# HDD to usb converter for 2.5 inch 5200RPM disk

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I want convert my laptop HDD to external HDD.

HDD configuration is:
Rotation Speed: 5200RPM
Size: 1TB

Which converter case is good for normal HDD? USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 as per speed.
As USB 3.0 is faster than 2.0, If I use USB 3.0 it will give maximum performance as HDD can give, but if I used 2.0 how much HDD performance will decrease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum USB 2.0 can ever transfer data is at 60 mb/s. (Read and write)

But in the case of your (2.5 inch) HDD the speed is likely to be 70-80 mb/s read or write. So if all you do is transfer files from the operating system (since all the drivers have been installed there) you shouldn't have any problems

The only reason you would really want to use USB 2.0 is in the case of booting operating systems on the go. Since USB 3.0 can be a bit of a pain to setup.

**The Answer**:

So you may as well take the usb 3.0 encloser adapter. But even if you use the USB 2.0 adapter you'll only loose between 5mb/s (or none) most of the time and 15mb/s at it's worst

Comment: why is USB3 a pain to setup, but USB2 isn't?

Comment: USB2 drivers for many chips are already built into many operating systems. USB3 is still to new. 

Best therefor is eSATA (no drivers needed, no overhead and very fast), USB2 (for compatability - but expect a speed of about 30-35MB/sec), and then USB3.

Comment: You won't find USB 3 to setup within an operating system such as windows or most Linux's. Only when booting operating systems from it